# cosmicmind horizontal layout children not display

Tags: cosmicmind

I want to use the following cosmicmind code to display two view horizontally, but it's just show nothing, could somebody tell me what's wrong with it?

my ios version is 10.2, cosmicmind version is 2.6.3

```
Layout.horizontally(parent: self.view,
            children: [leftImageView, rightImageView],
            left: 20,
            right: 20,
            interimSpace: 15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you do not have a height value for your views. Try setting a height value.